# Can't launch Stand-alone flash projector

Tags: flash

When I launch the program i get this error

./flashplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libXcursor.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

and when i do sudo apt-get install libxcursor1

it says it is already installed....

Answer (score 0):

I poked around at this.  Unfortunately, you need `i386` binaries for all the dependencies.  There's quite a list of these, and you even need to install the GTK+2 binaries, which are generally bad.  As well, the Linux launcher has a crash issue and crashes every time you try and use it, on 14.04.  This renders it unusable.

However, I had found another option.  There is much more smooth and better functionality in using the Windows standalone flash projector with Wine.  You can do this by installing `wine` and then using the Windows projector `.exe` file.  I suggest you use that route, as it is more smoothly-operable, and doesn't crash.