# How to install standalone Adobe Flash Player on Trusty

Tags: 14.04, flash

I want to play a .swf file using a standalone Adobe Flash Player on Trusty. AFAIK I was able to install Adobe's standalone Flash Player under Precise. However, Trusty won 't let me install version 10 (I think that it is 32 bit?) of it without installing ia32-libs package. Since that package no longer exists on Trusty, what do I do?

Comment: vlc used to attempt to play some type of web videos, flc or fls? Tried it?

Comment: Did you try the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FlashPlayerStandalone)? You may have to just accept needing either the 32-bit libraries or [Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546033/cant-launch-stand-alone-flash-projector).

Comment: BTW I tried Lightspark but it failed due to not being to play particular .swf file. I looked at Launchpad for Lightspark, it has 233 reported bugs & there seems to be no dev happening.

Comment: @Nattgew The instructions referred to "Adobe website (the page links to Windows, GNU/Linux and Mac files for the plugin and the standalone player - look for "Download the Linux debugger and standalone players")." whereas the referred-to Adobe website had this list "Linux

    DownloadDownload the Flash Player 11.2 Plugin content debugger
    DownloadDownload the Flash Player 11.2 Projector content debugger
    DownloadDownload the Flash Player 11.2 Projector".                                                     Should I use the Projector or the Projector...debugger?

Comment: Just tried downloading and running the Flash Player 11.2 Projector and it gives:                                                     
john@JohnDesktop:~/Downloads$ ./flashplayer 'Temporary/Her Laziness Queen of the Black Country Xmas Message.swf'
./flashplayer: error while loading shared libraries: libssl3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnRose you can try running it with `ldd` for more info but it's probably looking for the 32-bit version (unless you are missing libssl3)

Comment: @Nattgew actually I think the problem is that the flash file is a wrapper, and is simply a player for an actual video content stored elsewhere.  (There are many SWFs like this)

Answer (score 2):

The Standalone Flash Player for Windows can be used with Wine without issue, and actually is more efficient for Flash applications.  Unfortunately, VLC does not provide the intractability with interactive SWF files.

I have written a test result for this on the AppDB for Wine, [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31271).  Note that this is on a Trusty system with the Wine PPA.

Simply download the Windows executable (link on the AppDB), and run it to run your .SWF applications.  It should work out of the box with Wine with no additional configuration or DLLs needed.

Comment: Downloaded the Windows executable using AppDB link & ran it. When I opened the .swf file it displayed a blank window. I then tried running the .exe from the Terminal:
john@JohnDesktop:~/Downloads$ wine flashplayer_16_sa.exe 'Temporary/Her Laziness Queen of the Black Country Xmas Message.swf'
err:seh:raise_exception Exception frame is not in stack limits => unable to dispatch exception.
followed by lots of other messages.
I am emailable at johndotaarondotroseatgmaildotcom if you would like to try the relevant .swf file.

Comment: .swf file is downloadable from:
https://app.box.com/s/lx59ycbabujvcky4z4dz

Comment: .swf file is only 80kb: when I get Firefox to bring up that URL, it gives a blank page. So it looks like Wine & flashplayer are working. However, all other entries in Tools->Page Info (in Firefox) are not swf (or other video) files so my guess is that the .swf entry (shown as embedded) somehow refers to the real video file. The web page for playing the video clip is:
https://www.facebook.com/video.php?v=10152432831365653&set=vb.618775652&type=2&theater
The swf entry is:
https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v1/yZ/r/GCPgv5N0J7W.swf
Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnRose that seems like it might be a different kind of SWF, just a wrapper for a video playing.  I've seen such wrappers before, they dont' work standalone.  Unless opened in a web browser, this will fail each and every time.  The Standalone version for Linux (old by this day and age) would provide a similar result.

Comment: Any ideas how to download the video clip as a file, either .swf or .mp4 or any other video standard file?

Comment: I do not understand the use of single quotes / double quotes / forward slashes / backward slashes in .desktop files. I have problems with the Exec & Path statements below. Could you supply corrections to:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=AdobeProjector
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/john/.wine" wine C:/Program Files\\ \\(x86\\)/Adobe\\ Projector\\ 16\\.0\\\\flashplayer_16_sa.exe
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path="/home/john/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Adobe/Projector 16.0"
Icon=AdobeReader9

Comment: You don't need that at the command line... you don't even need to define the WINEPREFIX or anything... Open the executable on its own with a double click.  Exit the program.  Then just set the app to be used via the GUI for the SWF - right click the `.swf`, hit "Open With", select "A wine application" or "Adobe Flash ..." and hit "Select".  Then SWFs and such will run automatically with it.  (No need to use a whole Desktop launcher for it)

Answer (score 0):

Use vlc, open & play it.

The basics guide: http://www.ehow.com/how_7370013_open-swf-vlc.html

This is about replacing the flash player with vlc in your browser, so vlc should work stand-alone [VLC for flash video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54379/vlc-for-flash-video)

Comment: vlc gave a blank window. Please see my last comment to Thomas W above: it seems possible that the .swf file is currupted.

Comment: Same here, not blank but more like a 0 length do-nothing. Appears to be a "Macromedia Flash data (compressed), version 10" file, but vlc, totem, and actual flash in web browser didn't play anything